# Is there a way to jump to a line defined by a variable in C?

Tags: c, goto

So, I have this program, where I store the line number in a variable, using

```
int x = __LINE__;
```

The value of x can keep changing.
Is it possible to jump from an arbitrary line to the one given by x, using goto or any other keyword in C?
I'm looking for something like

```
'keyword' x;
```

where the program shifts to a line defined by the variable x.

Is there a workaround if this is not possible?

Comment: I can't imagine why you would ever want to do this...

Comment: The only way to have calculated gotos is through `switch`.

Comment: To do this doesn't make sense in any program. What is the actual problem that you are trying to solve?

Comment: even goto and label also works for same function only. I think you want this jumping for whole file right?

Comment: Since an expression can span multiple lines and a single line of code can contain multiple statements, a line based jump feature would be hard to justify

Comment: What does `x: /* ... */ goto x;` miss that you need ?

Comment: @Quentin No program should need a non-conditional jump upwards. That's just spaghetti programming and can be rewritten in better ways.

Comment: @Lundin we don't know whether it would be unconditional, but this is beside the point anyway.

Comment: `if (x == 1) goto LINE413; else if (x == 2) goto LINE036; else goto LINE209;` is, perhaps, a possible solution....

Comment: `if (feeling_lucky) write some comments above the function and see where the goto hits this time` @pmg whats the point of your comment?

Comment: @Quentin `goto` is called a non-conditional jump, since on assembler level it translates to a "branch always" instruction.

Comment: [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) much?

Comment: @Lundin oh, that's what you meant. Well there *are* algorithms where an `if(/*...*/) goto somewhereAbove;` (what I'd expect to call a *conditional* jump) cannot be replaced with a meaningful higher-level construct. But I missed the "`x` can change at runtime" part, so unwind's got the one answer to that.

Comment: @Quentin No, there are no such algorithms. `do while` is always clearer.

Comment: @Lundin crossed loops and FSMs come to mind. FSMs do have solutions that don't bend control structures too far, but crossed loops are a pain without `goto`.

Comment: @Quentin I have had this debate countless times before, but I have yet to see any code where this would actually be motivated. Whenever this is brought up, those who argue for non-conditional branches upwards always come up with some completely obfuscated code, like for example some case with nested loops, where the solution is always to rewrite the whole thing in better ways. As for FSMs, those are usually implemented with function pointer jump tables or a switch statement called from a loop or through a callback. Any other solution is likely of questionable quality.

Comment: goto goes only in function  where it is written...

Comment: @RosLuP thats right, but if you would want to jump to code in another function you would have to decide: (1) return from that function with undefined behavior, because the function exit is not matched by the function entry or (2) jump out of the function in order to restore a valid context - then WHY not have the code inside the original function to begin with?

Comment: the macro `__LINE__` expands precisely to the line where `x` so the value of `x` is not variable, but a constant to the line number where the macro appears in.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The GCC compiler supports, as an extension, [using labels as values](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Labels-as-Values.html) so that you can work with them in a way that resembles what you're after.

It allows you to do:

```
void *ptr = &&label;
label:
```

and then

```
goto *ptr;
```

to jump to `label`.

This is typically useful inside the core of a virtual machine, and can of course lead to horrible spaghetti. Also, again, it's a GCC extension (also supported by Clang, I think).

Comment: This is kind of what I was looking for. I was writing a program to print all the lines from a file, starting from the one specified by the user. I realize there are much better ways to do this, but I was just having fun.

Answer (score 0):

NO it's not possible, one possible way to achieve something similar is to define a variable as a function pointer and once you have set the variable to 
the correct function you call it.

```
int foo(int x) {
    return x+x;
}

int (*func) (int);
func = foo;
int r = func(3);
```

Answer (score 0):

That is possible but very painful. Suppose you have a program like this:

```
instruction1;
instruction2;
...
instructionn;
```

then you can rewrite it as:

```
jump:
switch(x) {
case 1:
  instruction1;
case 2:
  instruction2;
...
case n:
 instructionn;
}
```

You may then insert something like:

```
jump:
switch(x) {
case 1:
  instruction1;
case 2:
  instruction2;
...
case <something>:
  x = <number>;
  goto jump;
...
case n:
  instructionn;
}
```

Of course you will then encounter some problems encoding blocks like `switch` in such a schema, but it is always possible to translate it in this given form (not the place here to explain how). So depending on what you really have to do, I may not worth the effort.